# Azure Management Point-To-Site VPN: Get Connected clients / allocated ips

Tags: c#, .net, azure-virtual-network, azure-management-api, azure-vpn

I need to find a way to retrieve the currently allocated IPs for a point-to-site VPN (Type: OpenVPN).

I am using the C# with the Azure Management nuget packages.

For the context, there is only 1 kind of device connecting to the point-to-site and  sometimes, I need to contact them all to send them a command.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Based on the response of Nancy Xiong I came up with the following piece of code:

```cs
            var restClient = RestClient
                .Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithCredentials(creds)
                .Build();

            var networkClient = new NetworkManagementClient(restClient);
            networkClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

            try
            {
                var connectionHealth =
                    await networkClient.P2sVpnGateways.GetP2sVpnConnectionHealthAsync(resourceGroup,vnetGatewayName);
                var ipAddresses = connectionHealth.VpnClientConnectionHealth.AllocatedIpAddresses;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Network' for api version '2019-06-01'.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you could get allocated `privateIpAddress` via the REST API - [Get Vpnclient Connection Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-gateway/virtualnetworkgateways/getvpnclientconnectionhealth).

For Azure SDK for .net, you could get or set list of allocated IP addresses to the connected p2s vpn clients via [VpnClientConnectionHealth.AllocatedIpAddresses Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.network.fluent.models.vpnclientconnectionhealth.allocatedipaddresses?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Network_Fluent_Models_VpnClientConnectionHealth_AllocatedIpAddresses)

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="allocatedIpAddresses")]
public System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> AllocatedIpAddresses { get; set; }
```

Comment: That looks promising... How do you get your hands on the VpnClientConnectionHealth instance?

Comment: Try to use something like `await azure.networks.VirtualNetworkGateways.GetWithHttpMessagesAsync(string resourceGroupName, string virtualNetworkGatewayName)` refer to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/3dbbbe06d67ea2a5b040e0019dd6f690f95bf2b4/src/ResourceManagement/Network/Generated/VirtualNetworkGatewaysOperations.cs#L107). Or you also could consider to call the API in C# like [this](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/how-to-call-the-azure-resource-manager-rest-api-from-c/)

Comment: I tried both ways. The C# class you are linking to is internal so I can't use it. Using the Rest API returns NULL and that actually explains why the list of device ips is actually empty in the Azure Portal too. Gut feeling is that Microsoft did not implement that for the OpenVPN connection type. In other words, I don't think this is at all possible for the moment. Anyway, thanks for the hints!

Comment: If the Rest API returns NULL, I also think that Microsoft did not implement that for the OpenVPN connection type.